# What does $\int_0^1 x^n d\alpha(x)$ converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, stieltjes-integral

Let $\alpha$ be a monotonically increasing function on $[0,1]$. What does the sequence of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 x^n d\alpha(x)
\end{equation*}

converge to as $n \to \infty$?

I know that if $\alpha(x) = x$ then the sequence converges to $0$. More generally, if $\alpha(x)$ is continuous, then the sequence converges to zero. But what about for general monotone functions $\alpha(x)$?

Comment: What do the $x^n$ converge to pointwise? Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @PhoemeuX I do not know this theorem

Comment: It converges to $\alpha(1) - \alpha(1-)$, but I only know how to prove it using the dominated convergence theorem or the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @PhoemueX I tried that but had difficulty proving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this integral (with $0 < \epsilon < 1$) as

$$\int_0^1 x^n \, d\alpha =\int_0^{1-\epsilon}x^n \, d\alpha + \int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha $$

Considering the first integral on the RHS, we have

$$0 \leqslant  \int_0^{1-\epsilon}x^n \, d\alpha \leqslant (1-\epsilon)^n[\alpha(1) - \alpha(0)] \\ \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}x^n \, d\alpha = 0 $$

Considering the second integral, we have for all $n > 1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$

$$\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha \geqslant \int_{1-1/n^2}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha \geqslant \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^n[\alpha(1) - \alpha(1- 1/n^2)] \\ \implies \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha \geqslant \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-),$$

since $1 - 1/n \leqslant (1- 1/n^2)^n \leqslant 1$ using the Bernoulli inequality, and, hence, $(1-1/n^2)^n \to 1$.

We also have

$$\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha \leqslant \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-\epsilon) \leqslant \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-)$$

Thus,

$$ \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-) \leqslant \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha  \leqslant \limsup_{n \to \infty}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha \leqslant  \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-),$$

and it follows that

$$  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha =\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}x^n \, d\alpha  = \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-)$$

Comment: very clever, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @Mike: You're welcome.

Comment: @RRL: Nice solution! Minor point: Are you sure about the final step in the equation after "We also have"?

Comment: @PhoemueX This is because $x^n$ is bounded above by $1$ in $[1−\epsilon,1]$. Use the theorem which says that if $f_1≤f_2$ with $f_1,f_2$ integrable with respect to $\alpha$, then  $\int f_1 d\alpha \leq \int f_2 d\alpha$. It is not hard to see that $\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 1 d\alpha = \alpha(1) - \alpha(1-\epsilon)$. The last inequality follows from the monotonicity of $\alpha$

Comment: @PhoemueX:  I think Mike gives the justification.  Even if you drop the last inequality you have the integral bounded above by $\alpha(1) - \alpha(1-\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ and so the limsup must be les than or equal to $\alpha(1) - \alpha(1-)$.

Comment: Very nice argument. +1

Comment: @RRL: Exactly, I think you need to replace the last inequality by a limit.